# Bug in Toad when converting join from Oracle to ANSI notation?

Tags: oracle, toad

When using Toad to convert a query featuring outer joins written in the old Oracle notation into ANSI notation, I've run into a problem:

If I write it like this:

```
select AGENTS.AG_AGCLE, AGENTS.AG_NOM, S01_SERVICES.SE_CODE, 
    S01_DEPART.DP_CODE, S01_DEPART.DP_NOM, CONGES.CG_CPANT, 
    S01_PERSO.PE_TEMPSW, MEDWORK.MK_VILLE, MEDWORK.MK_DOCTORNAME 
from S01_PERSO,S01_SERVICES,S01_DEPART,AGENTS,CONGES,MEDWORK 
where SE_DPCLE=DP_DPCLE 
and SE_SECLE=PE_SECLE 
and PE_AGCLE=AG_AGCLE 
and AG_AGCLE=CG_AGCLE(+) 
and AG_MKCLE=MK_MKCLE(+)
and PE_PECLE=25;
```

Toad converts it to this, which is correct:

```
SELECT AG_AGCLE, AG_NOM, SE_CODE, DP_CODE, DP_NOM, CG_CPANT, PE_TEMPSW, 
    MK_VILLE, MK_DOCTORNAME
FROM S01_PERSO
INNER JOIN AGENTS ON (PE_AGCLE = AG_AGCLE)
INNER JOIN S01_SERVICES ON (SE_SECLE = PE_SECLE)
INNER JOIN S01_DEPART ON (SE_DPCLE = DP_DPCLE)
LEFT OUTER JOIN CONGES ON (AG_AGCLE = CG_AGCLE)
LEFT OUTER JOIN MEDWORK ON (AG_MKCLE = MK_MKCLE)
WHERE PE_PECLE = 25;
```

Whereas if I write it like this, which is the same query (I just wrote one of the join conditions the other way round):

```
select AGENTS.AG_AGCLE, AGENTS.AG_NOM, S01_SERVICES.SE_CODE, 
    S01_DEPART.DP_CODE, S01_DEPART.DP_NOM, CONGES.CG_CPANT, 
    S01_PERSO.PE_TEMPSW, MEDWORK.MK_VILLE, MEDWORK.MK_DOCTORNAME 
from S01_PERSO,S01_SERVICES,S01_DEPART,AGENTS,CONGES,MEDWORK 
where SE_DPCLE=DP_DPCLE 
and SE_SECLE=PE_SECLE 
and PE_AGCLE=AG_AGCLE 
and CG_AGCLE(+)=AG_AGCLE
and AG_MKCLE=MK_MKCLE(+)
and PE_PECLE=25;
```

Toad converts it to this:

```
SELECT AG_AGCLE, AG_NOM, SE_CODE, DP_CODE, DP_NOM, CG_CPANT, PE_TEMPSW, 
    MK_VILLE, MK_DOCTORNAME
FROM S01_PERSO
INNER JOIN AGENTS ON (PE_AGCLE = AG_AGCLE)
INNER JOIN S01_SERVICES ON (SE_SECLE = PE_SECLE)
INNER JOIN S01_DEPART ON (SE_DPCLE = DP_DPCLE)
LEFT OUTER JOIN MEDWORK ON (AG_MKCLE = MK_MKCLE)
RIGHT OUTER JOIN CONGES ON (CG_AGCLE = AG_AGCLE)
WHERE PE_PECLE = 25;
```

I have searched online for this problem and found nothing, Has anybody else come across this?  Is this a bug, or am I missing something?

I'm using Toad for Oracle Freeware 12.10.0.30, 64 bit on Windows 7 64 bit.

Comment: Update: The Toad dev team has confirmed it is a bug, patch will be released in version 12.11:)